# SVN/eclipse folder setup

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I have folders setup as follows

```
   My Projects
      Project1
         branches
         tags
         trunk
           src
           tests
           notes
           doc
     Project2
        ...
```

The above was stored into a local repository.  The above was put into the local repository using extract for Project1, branches and tags, and then using add/commit for src, tests, files, etc.

I have the following questions.

1) When I use repo browser in TortoiseSVN, at the top level I see what appears to be subdirectories from various src directories.  At the top level, in repo browser, I was expecting to see Project1, Project2, etc.  Did I do something wrong when creating the repository, or adding the files, or are my expectations for the organization in repo browser incorrect.

2) Once I get the folder setup correct, and am comfortable that repo browser shows that the setup is correct, then how to create eclipse projects around the above.  Everything is on my hard disk, the repository, and the current folders / files.  I'm using TortoiseSVN, and everything is "green".  To create the projects in eclipse, should first I "remove" the existing file structure before creating the projects, and then check folders/files back out of the repository?

3) Also, how do I remove the existing files/folders from the drive so that they are no longer associated with the repository.  I don't want to delete the files since that will delete the files/folders in the repository also

John

Comment: It's hard to see what your directory layout is as your formatting/indenting is lost. Please edit?

Comment: Could you by accident have made a number of repositories, rather than one repository with a folder strucure?

Comment: Your question is a little bit unclear, you should edit the following aspects: What is the scope (SVN repository or eclipse)? What tool do you use when you say repository browser, eclipse or TortoiseSVN? I don't understand the part `using extract for Project1, branches and tags ...`. What is your real question? Currently, there are (at least) 2: 1. `I see subdirectories under src.` 2. `How to create eclipse projects around the above?`

Answer (score 1):

1) Subversion stores informations strictly hierarchical fashion, the whole concept of trunk vs tags vs branches is purely convention. Some repositories are organized like this:

```
Project1
  trunk
    src
      main
      test
  tags
    beta-1
      ...
    release-2
      ...
  branches
    current-beta
      ...

Project2
  ...
```

This works well for unrelated projects -- Apache uses this.

If you are dealing with closely related projects, which may be releases, tagged, branches as a whole, you may do this differently, like this:

```
trunk
  Project1
    src
      main
      test
  Project2
    ...
```

tags
     beta-1
       ...
     release-2
       ...
   branches
     current-beta
       ...

Subversion doesn't care which you use, and the Repository Browser in TortoiseSVN or Subclipse won't care. If you open the repository, you will see the structure you've created.

2) With Subclipse (and likely Subversive, too), you can do the checkout outside Eclipse, and then use the Team > Share menu to connect the Subversion meta-information to your Eclipse workspace. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Here a try to your three questions.

### 1. Wrong structure in repository

If the repo browser shows you something like that:

```
http://machine.org/repos/MY_REPO   (no up icon)
branches
tags
trunk
  src
  test
```

(First line stands for the entry line in the repo browser, no up icon means that you see the root of the repository).
Then your structure is exactly like that. So there was something wrong, and you have to fix it.

You could use the repo browser itself to `create folder`s on the right side of the brower. Or you could call `add folder` to copy the structure from your local disk to the repository. Or you could checkout the root, create the structure locally, and add and commit it then to the repo.

### 2. Creating projects inside eclipse

There are different options to do that, @JesperSM has named one of them. Another could be to `Checkout` one project only in the `SVN repository exploring` perspective of Eclipse. The project will then be copied inside your workspace in Eclipse, even if you have some other place where you have checked out the whole files. If you use the mechanism of you SVN connector inside Eclipse, you can be assured that everything is setup ok. Eclipse will need additional files, and will create them if necessary.

### 3. Remove connection to repository

You don't want to loose the files, but you don't want that they are connected to the repository. The easiest way is to do an `export` from TortoiseSVN to a new directory, and then to remove the checkout location. You then have a fresh copy, without any information to Subversion then (so no danger that this will be reflected in the repository).